# how to print all the elements of the split in a generic way in python

Tags: python, scripting, split

I want to print all the elements of the split- whether the result of the split is a single element list or many elements. How many the splits happen is decided on run time.

For example-

```
x = "abc;bcd;def"
x1 = x.split(";")
print(x1[0], x1[1], x1[2])
```

However, x could sometimes be - `x =abc`, in that case `x1[1]` and `x1[2]` would return invalid/null and it screws up my code. Is there a generic way to print the results of the split, irrespective of the number of splits that happen?

I also want to print like this-

print(blah1, x1[0], blah2)- when the split results in only one element

If split results in more than one element, it will print each additional line for the additional element-

print(blah1, x1[0], blah2) #for element0 of the split

print(blah21, x1[1], blah21) #for element1 of the split

and so on (for every additional element of the split that is generated)..

Comment: Do you want to print all the elements with space in between?

Comment: Yes,  simply do: `print x` or `print " ".join(x)`

Comment: *"Is there a generic way"* - no, there are lots of generic ways. Just print the original x. Count how many there are in the list and work from that. `join()` the list back together and print that. Iterate over the items in the list and print those. Import pprint and pprint() the list...

Comment: Actually I want it printed like this-
print (blah1, x1[0], blah2)
print(blah12, x1[1], blah21)

Comment: Can you please update the question with what you mean by that? updates examples of expected result when split only results in 1 element and expected result when split results in 3 elements.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join back the split strings with whatever delimiter you want for printing. Example -

```
>>> x = "abc,bcd,def"
>>> x1 = x.split(',')
>>> print(' '.join(x1))
abc bcd def
```

Comment: You did not provide the answer to - *Can you please update the question with what you mean by that? updates examples of expected result when split only results in 1 element and expected result when split results in 3 elements.* .

Answer (score 3):

Pass the list to `print()` as separate arguments using the `*args` syntax:

```
print(*x1)
```

This expands the elements, however many there are, to pass them as individual arguments to the `print()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just print the result of the `split()` call:

```
x = "abc;bcd;def"
x1 = x.split(";")
print x1
```

It will work with any number of parts:

```
>>> print "a;b;c".split(";")
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print "a;b".split(";")
['a', 'b']
>>> print "a".split(";")
['a']
>>> print "".split(";")
['']
```